# Angular: HTTP Post always evoked second request when the first request is timeout

Tags: node.js, angular, post, observable

In my angular.js application, I have a button used to submit data to node.js. But when the processing take too long and exceed the timeout, there is another trigger in node.js and process the second time. I know `Observable` has `retry` function but I didn't use it.

myapp.component.ts

```
private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<{}> = new Subject();

constructor(private myappService: MyappService) {
}

onSubmit(): void {
    this.myappService.submit()
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
    .subscribe(result => {
        // handle result from HTTP Post
    });
}
```

myapp.service.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

submit(): Observable<any> {
    const url: string = "localhost/api/submit";
    return this.http.post<any>(url, {}).pipe(catchError(/* handle error */));
}
```

backend (node.js)

```
exports.submit = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('process');
    // process something but it exceeds timeout
    console.log('complete');
}
```

Here's my log when I click the button only 1 time.

```
process   // first and intended processing
process   // second and unintended process start when the first processing is exceed the timeout
complete  // the first processing still run into this code
complete  // the second processing
```

Express Router Config -

```
const router = require('express').Router(); 
const main = require('../controllers/main'); 
router.post('/api/submit', 
        (req, res, next) => { 
        main.submit(req, res, next); 
    });
 module.exports = router;
```

I would like to know what I have done wrong and make the HTTP post request trigger 2 times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see your Express router config?

Comment: are you using `proxy-config` in angular?

Comment: @ashishpal No, I don't.